# How to express this action: "a large heavy object may be laid accidentally on your toes"?

Tags: word-request, phrase-request

See this image, a large heavy stone may be laid accidentally on his toes

[image]

> [squash](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/squash_1?q=squash) [transitive] to press something so that it becomes soft, damaged or
>   flat, or changes shape
>
> **squash something/somebody** The tomatoes at the bottom of the bag had been squashed.
>
> Move up—you’re squashing me!
>
> **squash something against something** He squashed his nose against the window.
>
> **squash something + adj.** Squash your cans flat before recycling.

---

> **Note**: The object may **not fall from a higher position onto his toes**. The object may be so heavy that when he drag it & push it he may
>   accidentally lay it on his toes. And, sometimes **his toes may hurt
>   but not to a level that the toes become damaged**.

[This person says](https://hinative.com/en-US/questions/3763186)

> **Crush** is more often used for **hard objects**, like "I crushed the soda
>   can." **Squash** is usually for **soft things** like fruit. "She squashes the
>   rotten mangoes."

However, [the dictionary](http://www.learnersdictionary.com/definition/crush) says "**Unfortunately some of the flowers got crushed when we were moving them.**", so I assume "**crush**" can be applied for softer objects such as flowers or grapes.

[Ngram says](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=crush%20it%2Csquash%20it&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ccrush%20it%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Csquash%20it%3B%2Cc0) "**crush it**" is much more common than "**squash it**".

How do we express it "**Be careful!, The stone may squash your toes**"?

Comment: “Be careful of that stone, it might *break* (or *crush*) your toes/feet”

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To *lay something*, suggests something that is positioned with care and thought. You *lay a table*, someone *lays a trap*, an injured person is laid on a stretcher etc. If any object, heavy or light, is laid *accidentally* it means it was positioned in the wrong place or time.

> She noticed the keys he accidentally laid down on the table. Her eyes widened as she realized his mistake.

But in the image above, if the stone slips by accident it will *fall* on top of the victim's toes.

> Be careful if that stone falls, it might **crush** your toes.

A heavy object is likely to *crush* something that is weaker or softer. You crush grapes to make wine; crushed ice helps make a delicious *[granita](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Granita)*, instead of *cracking* nuts, we might crush them into small pieces.

> i. crushed beneath a bus
>   ii crushed between two cars

To *squash* something or *to be squashed* usually means to squeeze something or somebody in a tight space, if a pair of shoes are too small, your toes will feel squashed or cramped inside. You can feel squashed on some airplane seats. *Soft* fruit and vegetables are squashed if something heavy is placed on top.  Therefore, in the OP's example, the *bones* in a person's toes will be *crushed* under a thick heavy slab of stone.

Comment: I think a toe caught between a locomotive wheel and the rail would be completely ***squashed***, rather than ***crushed***. To my mind, *crushing* implies breaking bigger things into smaller things (or at least, inducing *fractures*) - but there are still "constituent parts" at the end of the process. But with enough pressure, the digit would effectively be converted to liquid / jam - ***squashed*** or ***mashed***. Think ***fruit squash***, or ***"smashed / crushed" potato*** as opposed to ***mashed potato***.